# How do I find the source of a Rails 3 "Deprecation Warning"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a deprecation warning from Rails 3 in development.log as follows:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling a method
>   in Rails::Application is deprecated,
>   please call it directly in your
>   application constant
>   MyApp::Application. (called from ...
>   config/environment.rb:5)

When I go to config/environment.rb, I get this:

> MyApp::Application.initialize!

Presumably this line is not the problem.  I found something similar [here](http://exviva.posterous.com/?tag=rails3), which seems to require exchanging Rails.Application for MyApp::Application - but I already have the latter.

Is there any way to determine what is triggering this warning?

Comment: Can you post your `config/environment.rb` file?

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing - here is what config/environment.rb looks like:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
MyApp::Application.initialize!
```